# how to filter records using C# and vue js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js

Front end (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrWtS.png).

Values in drop down are coming from database (SQL Server).

I want to display(filter) records according to selected options, from the list below (mentioned in png attachment).

Request that I created for drop downs:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/web/GetFilterYear")]
        public List<Years> GetFilterRecords(string year)
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                List<Years> xx = new List<Years>();
                xx = db.Database.SqlQuery<Years>("GetYears").*/ToList();
                return xx;
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/web/GetFilterMonth")]
        public List<Years> GetFilterMonth(string month)
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                List<Years> xx = new List<Years>();
                xx = db.Database.SqlQuery<Years>("GetFM").ToList();
                return xx;
            }
        }
```

Filter button

```
<div class="col-sm-2"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="margin-top:2px" onclick="GenerateTable()">Filter</button></div>
```

How can write generate table function using JavaScript for this code

Comment: If you want your solution in JavaScript you don't need to tag SQL Server.

Comment: you wouldn't generate a table on click in this situation, at least not with Vue.  Just build a table first that can display all the data without filters, then build the filter functionality on top of that.  with Vue you can easily update the data displayed in a table using Vue's built-in [reactivity system](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html) which is the main benefit of using a framework like Vue in the first place.